# If a Moran's I value is close to 1, then why is it necessary to report the p-value?

Tags: clustering, autocorrelation, spatial-cluster, moran-index

For instance, if we get a Moran's I value of around 0.6, then we already know based on that Moran's I value that spatial autocorrelation is present. Why is it important to additionally report the p-value?

Answer (score 3):

It is important to additionally report the p-value because Moran's I values are often not standardized and so they are not comparable to each other.

If you were trying to find the Moran's I of some attribute, let's say for example housing price on a block, here's how you would calculate it. First, you make a scatterplot, where each block is represented by a point. On the x-axis you would have the housing price on that block, and on the y-axis you would have the average housing price across all of that block's neighbors (the spatial lag of housing price). Moran's I is then the slope of the regression line that fits this data.  So you can think of moran's I as the slope (m) in a basic linear equation y = mx + b, where x = a given block's housing price and y = the average price of housing across the neighbor's of x).

What the p-value is telling you here is how likely that slope or a slope even further from zero than it is to happen, under the null hypothesis of complete spatial randomness. However, how likely that slope (or one more severe) is to happen is dependent on the spatial weights chosen to determine what exactly are the neighbors of block x. So, unless you are only comparing a very specific set of unstandardized Moran's I statistics, or you have standardized the Moran's I statistics in some other way, they are not comparable to each other.

Tl;dr while the sign of the Moran's I value can tell you whether the data exhibits positive or negative spatial autocorrelation, the p-value tells you how convinced you are the the autocorrelation is not just random noise. You need the p-value because in many cases it is the easiest way to compare different Moran's I statistics

Sorry the length got away from me there. I'm not sure what software you're using but here are some links I've found useful for working with and understanding moran's I:

https://mgimond.github.io/simple_moransI_example/#step_4:_computing_the_moran%E2%80%99s_i_statistic

https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/5a_global_auto/lab5a.html#concept